# Unable to hide button upon onload

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide the button when the form loads using a function (HideRemove()), and a onload tag script. However, for some reason it does not work. I have tried using .hidden on another part of my code and it works just fine. Any suggestions would be appreciated:

```
HTML: 

<div class="BuyRemoveButtonDiv">
          <button id="Button1">Add To Cart</button>
          <button id="Remove1" onload="HideRemove()">Remove From Cart</button>
          </div>

JS: 

function HideRemove() {
  let Remove1 = document.getElementById("Remove1");
  Remove1.hidden = true;
}
```

EDIT: Problem solved. Buttons do not have an "onload" event. The solution was to add a window event listener for load.

Comment: Button elements do not have an "onload" event. What is it you want it to do? When do you want it to happen?

Comment: Buttons don't trigger the `load` event. That event only occurs for elements that are loaded from a URL.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Basically I only want the "Remove From Cart" button to show when I click on "Add To Cart".

Comment: @user123456789 - Then set the remove button to `display: none` in css or give it a `hidden` property, so it's always hidden from the start, and *show* it with script in onclick for Button1 instead.

Comment: @Amunium thank you! I will definitely make a note of this.

Comment: You don't have to edit your question with the solution. Solutions are below the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Button doesn't have `onload`. You can use `window.onload` instead but I am not sure if this is what you want to achieve. Here's the example:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => HideRemove())

function HideRemove() {
    let Remove1 = document.getElementById("Remove1");
    Remove1.hidden = true;
}
```

```html
<div class="BuyRemoveButtonDiv">
    <button id="Button1">Add To Cart</button>
    <button id="Remove1">Remove From Cart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Solves my problem and I have learned something new. Thank you!

Comment: If what you want is for the remove button to be hidden from the start, until you click the other button, this is also not a good solution. No criticism of @blazej, they had no way of knowing what you wanted, but you shouldn't use script to hide something you want hidden from the start. Especially not on the `load` event, which will show it for a quick flash until the page loads.

Comment: You are right @Amunium but is wanted to give him an example of what he was doing wrong. I totally agree with that initial hidden property should be set using css

Comment: I have taken your suggestion and used css instead to hide the button. Under JS I used display = "inline"

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to hide the button when the form loads

A button doesn't trigger the load event, and neither does a form.  But the body does, and you can be confident your form has loaded when the body has loaded.

```js
function HideRemove() {
  let Remove1 = document.getElementById("Remove1");
  Remove1.hidden = true;
}
```

```html
<body onload="HideRemove()">
  <div class="BuyRemoveButtonDiv">
    <button id="Button1">Add To Cart</button>
    <button id="Remove1" onload="HideRemove()">Remove From Cart</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Because body has property `onload`. Buttons does not

Comment: Thank you. I have definitely learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

button is not a resource, it does not have the load event.
onload is used to img, body, css file, etc

```js
function HideRemove() {
  console.log("Open");
  let Remove1 = document.getElementById("Remove1");
  Remove1.hidden = true;
}
```

```html
<div class="BuyRemoveButtonDiv">
          <button id="Button1">Add To Cart</button>
          <button id="Remove1" onload="HideRemove()">Remove From Cart</button>
          </div>
```

```js
document.body.onload = ()=>{
  document.getElementById("Remove1").hidden = true;
};
```

```html
    <div class="BuyRemoveButtonDiv">
              <button id="Button1">Add To Cart</button>
              <button id="Remove1" onload="HideRemove()">Remove From Cart</button>
              </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help you to hide the 'Remove1' element.

```html
HTML: 

<div class="BuyRemoveButtonDiv">
          <button id="Button1">Add To Cart</button>
          <button id="Remove1" onload="HideRemove()">Remove From Cart</button>
          </div>

JS: 

function HideRemove() {
  let Remove1 = document.getElementById("Remove1");
  Remove1.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: .hidden = true works just fine, OP's problem is the onload event not working on buttons.

Comment: Good suggestion, I may try using it after modifying the logic of my code.

Comment: @user123456789 - Don't. That's not going to do anything.